# Override operator c#

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I would like to override operator * for my class. I know how to handle * for MyClass * MyClass but how can i implement this for having possibility to multiply for example:

7 * MyClass

7 is lets say double and MyClass is object of MyClass,

thanks for help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you provide an operator for your class, the parameter types for the operator implementation control which situations you're handling.

To illustrate:

```
// Declare which operator to overload (+), the types 
// that can be added (two Complex objects), and the 
// return type (Complex):
public static Complex operator +(Complex c1, Complex c2) 
{
   return new Complex(c1.real + c2.real, c1.imaginary + c2.imaginary);
}
```

This method defines what to do if you want to add two `Complex` numbers.

If you tried to use this with (say) a `double` and a `Complex`, compilation would fail.

In your case, you need just declare both versions:

```
public static MyClass operator *(MyClass c1, MyClass c2) 
{
   return ...
}

public static MyClass operator *(double n, MyClass c) 
{
   return ...
}
```

Comment: Note also that 7*MyClass is not the same as MyClass*7. You'll need two operator overloads to facilitate that.

Comment: There is no othe way the to write second operator overload?

Comment: If you want to support (double)*(MyClass) then this is how you do it. You sound as though this doesn't solve your problem - what's going wrong for you?

Comment: It solved the problem, I thought it would be perfect if .net can by itseflt determine which operator use when one double*myClass is implemented and myClass*double isnt then take this. I have to write second overload operator or remember to use it in correct order.

Comment: I'm guessing that, in your case, (double)*(MyClass) will always be the same as (MyClass)*(double). While this symmetry might hold for you, and certainly holds for regular multiplication, not every use of "*" as an operator is symmetric, and other operators (e.g. "/" "-" "%") are seldom if ever symmetric. This is likely the reason .NET forces you to be explicit about both cases.

Answer (score 2):

The appropriate signature in this case is:

```
public static MyClass operator *(double a, MyClass b)
```

This means it takes a `double` as the left side, a `MyClass` as the right, and returns a `MyClass`.